# I am unable to post my json to my api lambda function.I am getting {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-lex

[image][image]Actually everything runs fine when I import the json to my POSTMAN application and send the request .But problem arises when I try to POST using an ajax call or directly hit the api

I had tried to remove api key and made every authorization none

This is my API - https://ym4j4pt5mf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Beta
And I am trying to post this as raw body:-

```
{
  "DestinationBot": "iSearchBot",
  "SenderID": "12345",
  "botAlias": "iSearchBotBeta",
  "message": {
    "text": "hi"
  }
}
```

This is the response that I get when I hit the api by importing it from api gateway  via POSTMAN

```
{
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "65e1b452-65e4-11e9-ab8a-d328589017aa",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "date": "Tue, 23 Apr 2019 16:25:25 GMT",
            "x-amzn-requestid": "65e1b452-65e4-11e9-ab8a-d328589017aa",
            "content-length": "709",
            "connection": "keep-alive"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    },
    "intentName": "HotelReservation",
    "slots": {
        "FromDate": null,
        "Location": null,
        "adultCount": null,
        "checkOutDate": null,
        "childCount": null,
        "childExists": null,
        "noOfRooms": null,
        "searchHotel": null,
        "welcome": null
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "message": "I am iSearchBot,I can help you book a hotel",
    "messageFormat": "PlainText",
    "dialogState": "ElicitSlot",
    "slotToElicit": "welcome",
    "responseCard": {
        "version": "1",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
        "genericAttachments": [
            {
                "title": "Do you want to book a Hotel",
                "imageUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1034820690463997957/TZEsJwEa_400x400.jpg",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "text": "Yes",
                        "value": "Yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "No",
                        "value": "No"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance any help will be great

Comment: Like the message says, you are lacking authentication token. Probably AWS uses JWT or Bearer. The two need to be passed as headers.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Can you review your url? Amazon says "If the method does not exist you will get back "Missing Authentication Token" and the HTTP METHOD TOO: some endpoints are method restricted.

Comment: Ok i think i know what it is, what languages are you using? E.g.: nodeJS, vue, etc.

Comment: Python in Lambda and jquery ajax for POST xhr request I have added two pictures you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this will solve your problem i guess the problem was with json stringify it works easily

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var value={ 
  'DestinationBot': "iSearchBot",
  'SenderID': "12345",
  'botAlias': "iSearchBotBeta",
  'message': {
    'text': "hi"
  }
};
value = JSON.stringify(value);
$.ajax({
  url:'https://ym4j4pt5mf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Beta/',
  headers:{  
    'Content-Type': "application/json",   
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  method:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  data:value,
  success:function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
  }
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i don't know exactly your setup, but i will point you the direction. The problem is the request needs to be done with it's raw body and type application/json. The key here is the "Content-Type" and the payload JSON. If you are not using this exactly lib, i'm sure the other one will have similar options.

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ym4j4pt5mf,execute-api,us-east-1,amazonaws,com")

payload = "{\n  \"DestinationBot\": \"iSearchBot\",\n  \"SenderID\": \"12345\",\n  \"botAlias\": \"iSearchBotBeta\",\n  \"message\": {\n    \"text\": \"hi\"\n  }\n}"

headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/json",
  'cache-control': "no-cache",
  'Postman-Token': "0de52364-daf7-4977-8b82-55d5258a4046"
  }

conn.request("POST", "Beta", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Or if you use Requests:

```
import requests

url = "https://ym4j4pt5mf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Beta"

payload = "{\n  \"DestinationBot\": \"iSearchBot\",\n  \"SenderID\": \"12345\",\n  \"botAlias\": \"iSearchBotBeta\",\n  \"message\": {\n    \"text\": \"hi\"\n  }\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "245fea6e-5604-47dd-96ec-745ae2b6cde0"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: can you  you write this in jquery ajax

Comment: What lib are you using for Javascript?

Comment: only jquery nothing else

Comment: You are almost there. You need to set the content type of the "Response" to application/json and use jquery ajax functions like: $.ajax({ type: 'post', dataType: 'application/json', success: function (response) { console.log(response)  } })

Everything you send at your python function becomes a JSON object.

Comment: Still I am getting CORS Error ie Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ym4j4pt5mf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Beta/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: I have added the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*" yet I am getting this problem

Comment: You need to make a request to your domain, inside that request you call this address. This is because you cannot make a cross call to another domain in the browser.